# How to get list of stored procedure in a namespace of Caché database using a query?

Tags: intersystems-cache

How to get list of stored procedures available in a namespace from an Intersystems Caché database using query?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM %Dictionary.CompiledMethod WHERE SqlProc = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query the table

%sql_dict.routine

to obtain the information you are looking for.